# Call Method in Method

Tags: php, mysql

I want to ask something about philosophy of MVC - model side. I've got 2 methods, getStory & getStoryWithText, which one of getStoryWithText is more effective?

```
 <?php

    public function getStory($storyID) {
    return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM #__stories WHERE storyID = '$storyID'");
    }

    //variant A
    public function getStoryWithText($storyID) {
    return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM #__stories s, #__stories_text st WHERE s.storyID = '$storyID' AND s.storyID = st.storyID");
    }

    //variant B
    public function getStoryWithText($storyID) {
    $data["info"] = $this->getStory($storyID);
    $data["text"] = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM #__stories_text st WHERE st.storyID = '$storyID'");
    return $data;
    }

    ?>
```

Is varint A better because of one Select? Or is variant B better because there is easier SQL and Iam also calling another SQL? Is generally great idea to call method with SQL to another method or I should make SQL for every situations witch can happend. Iam confused, please give me some advices.

Comment: None of this code seems sql-injection safe.

Comment: Dont worry, variable is transfered already protected.

Comment: So, you obviously have no idea what [prepared statements](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) are ..

Comment: "Are already protected" is the wrong attitude. You have absolutely no guarantee that anything is protected here. An oversight in a completely different part of your codebase could lead to SQL injection here. You must always take care of vulnerabilities at the point where they may occur, not "elsewhere".

Comment: Does somebody recognized what is my point? Iam asking if two simple queries are better than one harder query. In this case. Or I should create sql queries for every method I have. Please, reply to me just about my topic, thnx much!

Comment: And thnx for your carying about my SQL protection, but be cool, I use part of Nette framework to protect my sql queries 8-)